# How to increment a specific number in a formula when dragging formula across a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the following formula:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($B$2:$B$700)=3),--('[$O$2:$O$700="CDE"))
```

I want to drag it across a row and automatically change the spot where the '3' is every time for each month.

How can I increment the month number in this formula?

We have columns with the following headings like:

`Jan-15 Feb-15... Dec-15`

So I've tried to use

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($B$2:$B$700)=MONTH(A1)),--('[$O$2:$O$700="CDE"))
```

A1 in the upper formula being the Cell number for January, B1 for February, etc. Theoretically this should work but I keep getting `0` as my result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Column(A1) instead of Month(A1) (Although Month should work assuming your data is a proper date and not a textual one).

Answer (score 2):

The [COLUMN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COLUMN-function-44E8C754-711C-4DF3-9DA4-47A55042554B) returns the numerical index.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($B$2:$B$700)=COLUMN(C:C)),--('[$O$2:$O$700="CDE"))
```

Comment: Problem is that now I get the value '1' for everything.